# Is there a way to list what types of key ssh-keygen supports?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

The man page for ssh-keygen on my system (Fedora 35) says that the following types of keys are supported:

```
-t dsa | ecdsa | ecdsa-sk | ed25519 | ed25519-sk | rsa
         Specifies the type of key to create.  The possible values are
         “dsa”, “ecdsa”, “ecdsa-sk”, “ed25519”, “ed25519-sk”, or “rsa”.
```

Is there a way to consult this list at runtime, by passing some special flags to `ssh-keygen` or some other script? Or is this list of types hardcoded and only specified in this man page? The reason I ask this is that I want to teach my shell how to autocomplete the `-t` parameter.

Comment: AFAICT `ssh -Q key` would list the ones that `ssh-keygen` would accept, but I'm not sure it would be able to generate a key for everyone  of those types.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think theres is: The key type needs to be in [this](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_9_P1/ssh-keygen.c#L268-L297) list (switch to a tag representing the release of openssh you're using instead of "V_8_9_P1" on top of the page):

```
        case KEY_DSA_CERT:
        case KEY_DSA:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_DSA;
            break;
#ifdef OPENSSL_HAS_ECC
        case KEY_ECDSA_CERT:
        case KEY_ECDSA:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ECDSA;
            break;
        case KEY_ECDSA_SK_CERT:
        case KEY_ECDSA_SK:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ECDSA_SK;
            break;
#endif
        case KEY_RSA_CERT:
        case KEY_RSA:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_RSA;
            break;
        case KEY_ED25519:
        case KEY_ED25519_CERT:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ED25519;
            break;
        case KEY_ED25519_SK:
        case KEY_ED25519_SK_CERT:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ED25519_SK;
            break;
        case KEY_XMSS:
        case KEY_XMSS_CERT:
            name = _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_XMSS;
```

There's no way to query this. I can understand why – this would be easy in C++, or any other modern language, but C not only doesn't bring any "map<key, value>" types in its standard library, it also does make building such safely, or using them, relatively hard.

So, C code is littered with `switch`/`case` (or, if the key can't be converted to an integer, `if/`else if`) chains, and printing a list of accepted keys will simply require another one, which needs extra maintenance effort to keep in lockstep with the actual logic :(

Comment: You're omitting the important part of that code where the "type" there is derived from the argument passed to `-t` by comparing it against the long and short name fields of a  table. `ssh -Q key` dumps the long names of that table, not the short ones.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes `ssh -Q key`

Note the list in `--help` is hard coded and will exclude experimental keys that `ssh-keygen` may have been compiled to support [like xmss](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/268282/11447). The command `ssh -Q key` will show all valid arguments to `ssh-keygen -t` assuming, they were both compiled with

- the same options
- the same libraries

---

This answer is inspired by the comment by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693883/is-there-a-way-to-list-what-types-of-key-ssh-keygen-supports/734700#comment1311941_693883). They make mention *"I'm not sure it would be able to generate a key for everyone of those types."* I've checked that they're all supported with,

```
for c in $(ssh -Q key); do ssh-keygen -t "$c"; done < /dev/null
```